# Python - Get policy year from datetime dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (df) with a column in datetime format YYYY-MM-DD ('date'). I am trying to create a new column that returns the policy year, which always starts on April 1st and thus the policy year for January through March will always be the prior calander year. There are dates that are rather old so setting up individual date ranges for the sample size below wouldn't be ideal

The dataframe would look like this

```
df['date']

    2020-12-10
    2021-02-10 
    2019-03-31
```

and output should look like this

```
2020 
2020 
2018
```

I now know how to get the year using `df['date'].dt.year`. However, I am having trouble getting the dataframe to convert each year to the respective policy year so that `if df['date'].dt.month >= 4` then `df['date'].dt.year`, `else df['date'].dt.year - 1`

I am not quite sure how to set this up exactly. I have been trying to avoid setting up multiple columns to do a bool for month >= 4 and then setting up different columns. I've gone so far as to set up this but get ValueError stating the series is too ambiguous

```
def PolYear(x):
  y = x.dt.month
  if y >= 4:
    x.dt.year
  else:
    x.dt.year - 1

df['Pol_Year'] = PolYear(df['date'])
```

I'm wasn't sure if this was the right way to go about it so I also tried a df.loc format for >= and < 4 but len key and value are not equal. Definitely think I'm missing something super simple.

I previously had mentioned 'fiscal year', but this is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quang Hoand had the right idea but used the incorrect frequency in the call to `to_period(self, freq)`. For your purposes you want to use the following code:

```
df.date.dt.to_period('Q-MAR').dt.qyear
```

This will give you:

```
0    2021
1    2021
2    2019
Name: date, dtype: int64
```

Q-MAR defines fiscal year end in March

These values are the correct fiscal years (fiscal years use the year in which they end, not where they begin[[reference]](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/f/fiscalyear.asp#:%7E:text=A%20fiscal%20year%20is%20a,purposes%20to%20prepare%20financial%20statements.)). If you you want to have the output using the year in which they begin, it's simple:

```
df.date.dt.to_period('Q-MAR').dt.qyear - 1
```

Giving you

```
0    2020
1    2020
2    2018
Name: date, dtype: int64
```

[qyear docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Period.qyear.html#pandas-period-qyear)

Answer (score 0):

This is `qyear`:

```
df.date.dt.to_period('Q').dt.qyear
```

Output:

```
0    2020
1    2021
2    2019
Name: date, dtype: int64
```